# Controller variable not updating before Custom-Directive operation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new at angularJS (I know it is late to learn angularJS but better now than never..Right?) and have been playing around with it with some simple tasks.
recently i was trying to dive deeper into how data is interchanged, updated among Controllers, Custom Directives, and controller of Custom Directive.
In a simple implementation I tried to create a click counter in custom-directive controller, which will initiate the count variable from main controller, will do count operation on that variable in the custom-directive. In custom-directive there are two count operations. First operation is count +1 and second operation is on another variable +2. Then by clicking a button "CLICK" A function from main controller is invoked which then multiplies the both counts and produces the result.

Here, the problem i am facing is when:

Single Increment: 1
Double Increment: 2
Result: 0 (should be: 2)

Single Increment: 2
Double Increment: 4
Result: 4 (should be: 8)

Single Increment: 3
Double Increment: 6
Result: 12 (should be: 18)

Single Increment: 4
Double Increment: 8
Result: 24 (should be: 32) vice-versa....

meaning that the '$scope.count' in controller of custom-directive is incremented on the "onClick()"event  but the '$scope.count' of the main controller IS NOT incremented at "onClick()" event, rather it retains the previous value although both-way-binding is in action.

What to do to overcome this problem?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.result = 0;

  $scope.increase = function(dircount) {
    $scope.result = dircount * $scope.count;
  };
});

myApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><div>Increment from Directive: SINGLE INCREMENT {{singleInc}} times</div>' +
      '<div><button  ng-click="click()">CLICK</button></div></div>',
    scope: {
      counT: '=',
      onClick: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.singleInc = 0;
      $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.singleInc++;
        $scope.counT += 2;
        $scope.onClick({
          item: $scope.singleInc
        });

      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myModule"> 

<head><title> Click-Counter Multiplier</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js" </script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity = "sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin = "anonymous" >
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p>Result: {{result}}</p>
    <p>From Controller: DOUBLE INCREMENT {{count}}</p>
    <hello-world coun-t="count" on-click="increase(item)"></hello-world>
    </br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because two-way (`=`) binding involves a digest cycle delay between the isolate scope of the directive and the scope of the parent controller.

One approach to avoid the delay is to use expression (`&`) binding for changes:

```
myApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    replace: true,
    template: `
        <div>
          <div>Increment from Directive: SINGLE INCREMENT {{singleInc}} times
          </div>
          <div>
            <button ng-click="click()">CLICK</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    `,
    scope: {
      counT: '<',
      counTChange: '&',
      onClick: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.singleInc = 0;
      $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.singleInc++;
        $scope.counT += 2;
        $scope.counTChange({$event: $scope.counT});
        $scope.onClick({
          item: $scope.singleInc
        });    
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<hello-world coun-t="count" cont-t-change="count=$event" on-click="increase(item)">
</hello-world>
```

It makes the template more complicated, but it avoids the digest cycle delay that causes problems.

This is the way that Angular 2+ does it with banana-in-a-box (`[(coun-t)]=count`) syntax.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg for reply. Your solution works like a charm when the controller and directive is in a single file. 
But, when they are located in seperate files the variables of the controller does not change due to your dynamic '<' binding. Your theoretical reasoning is perfect but there is a problem somewhere.when i divide them (into directive.js and controller.js) project the problem i posted in the first place prevails again. The solution i found best was in Directive.js:
'[scope: {counT: '=',onClick: '&'}]'
`$timeout(function () {$scope.onClick({ item: $scope.singleInc });}, 0)`Done!